# "Says we"—Why is "say" in its 3rd person singular form?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

This is a line from O' Henry's The Ransom of Red Chief :

> Philoprogenetiveness, says we, is strong in semirural communities.

Is this use of *says* grammatical in general, or is it peculiar to O' Henry's dialect? If its generally grammatical, which rule endorses its validity?

Comment: It is peculiar to the dialects that O. Henry's characters speak. It is not generally grammatical, and was considered at the time he wrote (around 1900) a sign of low educational status.

Comment: *"Unsophisticated?"*, I says. *"**Moi**?"*

Answer (score 1):

The expression is grammatically incorrect, as you think. You could say it is incorrect accidence rather than incorrect syntax.

But I think it is a deliberate ‘mistake’ and so not really a mistake at all.  I do not know the origin, but there is a kind of agressive conversation that goes as follows:-

“If you keep parking that van in front of my living room windows, you’re going to regret it.”
“Says who?”
“Says me!”

You could call it a kind of grammatical slang.  The normal order for the question would be “who says?”.  Reversing the standard order increases the force of the word ‘who?’.  You can imagine the van driver thrusting his chest out at the irate householder.  So it is a sort of literary device.  The householder, instead of saying the grammatically correct “I say”, mirrors the structure of his adversary with “Says me”.

But why ‘me, when it should be ‘I’?  Well, had he answered in one word, that word would have been ‘me’.  It is not the nominative, but it has a rhetorical force.

I have not heard this colloquialism used with a first person plural before, but the same principles apply.

Comment: This is quite a different thing, I’m afraid. This is purely dialectal. “I says” and “we says” are both quite common in some dialects of the British Isles, and this is one such case.